# Access state of object (tkinter, Python3) beginner's level

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, state

What I want to get: change of checkbox state changes the state of the Entry widget from 'disabled' into 'normal'. (checkbox off = Entry disabled, checkbox on = Entry normal).
My problem is that I don't know how to access and update the state of entry.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, padding='20')
        self.grid()
        self.create_checkbox()
        self.create_entry()

    def create_checkbox(self):
        self.limit = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text='Limit length',
                    variable= self.limit,
                    command= self.state_update,
                    ).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

    def create_entry(self):
        self.entry_low = StringVar()
        Entry(self,
              width=6,
              textvariable=self.entry_low,
              state='disabled',
              ).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)


    def state_update(self):
        self.entry_low.config(state="normal")  #THIS OBVIOUSLY DOES NOT WORK

root = Tk()
root.title("Lottery")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm beginner, so I'd be especially grateful for simple solutions.

Comment: You'll want to add a [`StringVar()` or `BooleanVar()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) to the checkbutton and then look into adding a trace to that StringVar.  Once you have the trace set up you can use it to detect when the checkbutton is changed and update the Entry's state accordingly.

Comment: @Jkdc: no need for a trace. That's what the `command` attribute is for.

Comment: @Jkdc, Thanks! Obviously haven't thought about it and that worked well for me. I'll try also solution given below by Bryan.

Comment: @BryanOakley D'oh forgot about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a reference to the entry widget, then call the `configure` method. To make things easy, give your checkbutton the values for the states. That isn't strictly necessary, you can use a boolean and then translate that to the appropriate state.

```
def create_checkbox(self):
    self.limit = StringVar(value="normal")
    checkbutton = Checkbutton(..., onvalue="normal", offvalue="disabled", ...)
    checkbutton.grid(...)

def create_entry(self):
    self.entry_low = StringVar()
    self.entry = Entry(self,
          width=6,
          textvariable=self.entry_low,
          state='disabled',
          )
   self.entry.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)

def state_update(self):
    self.entry.config(state="normal")  #THIS OBVIOUSLY DOES NOT WORK
```

---

Note: you need to call `grid` in a second step. `grid(...)` (as well as `place`) returns `None`. If you do `x=Entry(...).grid(...)`, `x` will always be `None`.